# Create a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

Create a trigger called NewEntry, that will not allow a result to be inserted into the student exam table if it is less than zero. In your query display a suitable message if the result is less than zero and supply code to test the trigger.

This is what I have done, but I keep getting

> warning : trrigger created with compilation errors.

This is my code, please help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NewEntry 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Assignment2.Student_Exam 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
Results NUMBER;
BEGIN
IF(:NEW.Results < '0')
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
(-20700,'Student's result cannot be less-than ZERO..Enter valid Results':);
ENDIF;
END;
 /
```

Comment: What does `show errors` show you? Btw: `'0'` is not a number, it's a character literal. `0` is a number

Comment: i changed it but its still displaying "warning : trrigger created with compilation errors."

Comment: And the errors are? Errors have some meaning, so why to hide them? Show us the errors.

Comment: i'm having a difficulty finding the error because the error that my compiler is showing is "warning : trigger created with compilation errors."

Comment: probably not the problem but you need to create this trigger before insert or update because otherwise you can't prevent from inserting the row

Answer (score 0):

END IF, not ENDIF. Also as Jeremy C mentions above you need to create the trigger as BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE

Comment: Then you've probably more than one syntax error. The compilation errors will be listed somewhere, what tool are you using to build the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors: Firstly it is 'END IF' not ENDIF, secondly you have apostrophe's in your message.

The correct code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NewEntry 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Assignment2.Student_Exam 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
Results NUMBER;
BEGIN
IF(:NEW.Results < '0')
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
(-20700, 'students result cannot be less-than ZERO..Enter valid Results:');
END IF;
END;
 /
```

As others have said you could have de-bugged this yourself by typing show errors;   This would have given you the answer e.g.

```
SQL> show errors;
Errors for TRIGGER NEWENTRY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
7/18     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "S" when expecting one of the
following:
) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

edit: In reply to Ersin - If it was New.Results then you would get a bind error e.g.

```
SQL> show errors;
Errors for TRIGGER NEWENTRY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/4      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.RESULTS'
SQL>
```

This will be a result of 'RESULTS' not being a column in Student_Exam, which I presume does exist given the rest of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

you listen the other answers but one more thing ,

you must focus on **:NEW.Results**  this is the thing.